# how to create trigger with cases

Tags: mysql, oracle, triggers

I have oracle 11g db.i want to create a trigger on a table named as `GG_TEST_SMS_LOG`. the table have one column named as `SMS_LOG_ORIG`.where 10 digits numeric value exists.

Now i want if a new row inserted in the table `GG_TEST_SMS_LOG`, if column value `SMS_LOG_ORIG` last digit is like 1 then row will be inserted into the another table named as `GG1_TEST_SMS_LOG`.

like this we have 10 tables `GG<N>_TEST_SMS_LOG`. where N value is 0 to 9.the new row should insert in another table depending upon last number of digits of column value `SMS_LOG_ORIG`.

Comment: What has `mysql`got to do with your question?

Answer (score 0):

To determine the last digit of a number you can do something like

```
DECLARE
  cLast_digit  CHAR(1);
  n            NUMBER := 12345;
BEGIN
  cLast_digit := SUBSTR(TO_NUMBER(n), -1);
END;
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope this code snippet illustrates the problem discussed. Let me know if this helps.

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "AVROY"."TRI_CHCK_TRIGGER" AFTER
  INSERT OR
  UPDATE ON TRI_CHCK FOR EACH ROW DECLARE LV_ERR_CODE_OUT NUMBER;
  LV_ERR_MSG_OUT VARCHAR2(2000);
  BEGIN
    IF SUBSTR(:new.ID_NO,LENGTH(:NEW.ID_NO),LENGTH(:NEW.ID_NO)) = 1 THEN
      INSERT INTO EMP
        (EMPNO
        ) VALUES
        ( :new.ID_NO
        );
    ELSIF SUBSTR(:new.ID_NO,LENGTH(:NEW.ID_NO),LENGTH(:NEW.ID_NO)) = 2 THEN
      INSERT INTO EMP_V1
        (EMPNO
        ) VALUES
        ( :new.ID_NO
        );
    END IF;
  END;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get the last digit is to use `MOD()`:

```
with v_data(pk) as (
  select 100000+level 
  from dual
  connect by level <= 10
)
select pk, mod(pk, 10) from v_data
```

So, all you have to do is use `MOD(<column name>, 10) = 1` to check whether the last digit is a 1. Integrating this into your trigger should be pretty straightforward.